# Is there a way to get data for all Google Fitness users?

Tags: google-fit

I want to develop android application using google fitness api. I would like to provide a useful service by comparing based on a lot of user data.
Is there a way to get data for all Google Fitness users?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain data for users for whom you have an OAuth token; the scopes on that token determine which data you will be able to access.

But for *all* users? Good grief, no.